# VHDL - Quartus II inferring latches on circuit

Tags: vhdl, latch, quartus-ii

My circuit is based on a state-machine. I checked it and it's working fine, the only issue is that it's inferring one latch per flip-flop (The state machine has 11 states and the circuit is one-hot so it has 11 flip-flops, but also 11 unwished latches)
I have checked everything but I cant find what it causing these unexpected latches. My code is in spanish, I think this shouldnt be a problem, but if you need me to translate it, I can do it. The only important note is that "estado" means "state" and "estaprox" means "next state".
Many thanks for your help

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ej13 is 

port (
        clk_i   :   in std_logic;
        y_i :   in std_logic;
        sr_i    :   in std_logic;
        z_o :   out std_logic);

end entity ej13;

architecture EstaNoAsig of ej13 is
    type tipo_estado is (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k);
    signal estado, estaprox : tipo_estado;
begin

Secuencial:
process (clk_i)
begin
    if rising_edge (clk_i) then
        if  sr_i = '1' then
            estado <= a;
        else
            estado <= estaprox;
        end if;
    end if;
end process Secuencial;

Combinacional:
process (y_i, estado)
begin
    case estado is
        when a =>
            if y_i = '1' then
                estaprox <= c;
                z_o <= '1';
            else
                estaprox <= b;
                z_o <= '0';
            end if;

        when b =>
            if y_i = '1' then
                estaprox <= e;
                z_o <= '1';
            else
                estaprox <= d;
                z_o <= '0';
            end if;

        when c =>
            if y_i = '1' then
                estaprox <= e;
                z_o <= '0';
            else
                estaprox <= d;
                z_o <= '1';
            end if;

        when d =>
            if y_i = '1' then
                estaprox <= g;
                z_o <= '1';
            else
                estaprox <= f;
                z_o <= '0';
            end if;

        when e =>
            if y_i = '1' then
                estaprox <= g;
                z_o <= '0';
            else
                estaprox <= f;
                z_o <= '1';
            end if;

        when f =>
            if y_i = '1' then
                estaprox <= i;
                z_o <= '1';
            else
                estaprox <= h;
                z_o <= '0';
            end if;

        when g =>
            if y_i = '1' then
                estaprox <= i;
                z_o <= '0';
            else
                estaprox <= h;
                z_o <= '1';
            end if;

        when h =>
            if y_i = '1' then
                estaprox <= k;
                z_o <= '1';
            else
                estaprox <= j;
                z_o <= '0';
            end if;

        when i =>
            if y_i = '1' then
                estaprox <= k;
                z_o <= '0';
            else
                estaprox <= j;
                z_o <= '1';
            end if;

        when j =>
            if y_i = '1' then
                estaprox <= a;
                z_o <= '1';
            else
                estaprox <= a;
                z_o <= '0';
            end if;

        when k =>
            if y_i = '1' then
                estaprox <= a;
                z_o <= '0';
            else
                estaprox <= a;
                z_o <= '1';
            end if;

        when others =>
            z_o <= '0';
            estaprox <= a;

    end case;
end process Combinacional;
end architecture EstaNoAsig;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some default assignments:

```
process (y_i, estado)
begin
  --default assignments
  estaprox <= estado;    -- stay in the current state, unless the case statement calculates a 'jump'
  z_o      <= '0';       -- assign all outputs with a default value to prevent latches

  -- next state calculations
  case estado is
    when a =>
      if y_i = '1' then
        estaprox <= c;
        z_o      <= '1';
  [...]
  end case;
end process Combinacional;
```

Three additional hints:

- Some time in the future, you'll get into trouble with these short state names, if you decide to use these also as signal names: One solution could be a prefix "st_" for every state name.
- Signal estado should have a default value (start-up value):
  `signal estado : tipo_estado := a;`
- You can shorten some states, if you want to :)

  ```
  when j =>
    estaprox <= a;
    z_o      <= y_i;

  when k =>
    estaprox <= a;
    z_o      <= not y_i;
  ```

Comment: I added  estaprox <= estado; and z_o      <= '0', but it's still the same, not working. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That's strange I can find any other 'bug'. Adding these two lines should have solved the problem. Have you recompiled everything from scratch? -- One more question: do you have 11 latches in stead of 11 flip flops, or do you have 22 memory elements: 11x flip flop and 11x latch? Does Quartus report for which signal it infers the latches?

Comment: Yes, I recompile everything. I have 11 flip-flops + 13 logic elements.